# How to handle executor failure in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have run the job using spark-submit while that time we lost executor and the certain point we can recover or not if recover how we will recover and while how we have to get back that executor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot handle executor failures programmatically in your application, if thats what you are asking. 
You can configure spark configuration properties which guides the actual job execution including how YARN would schedule jobs and handle task and executor failures.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling

Some important properties you may want to check out:

> spark.task.maxFailures(default=4):    Number of failures of any particular task
>   before giving up on the job. The total number of failures spread
>   across different tasks will not cause the job to fail; a particular
>   task has to fail this number of attempts. Should be greater than or
>   equal to 1. Number of allowed retries = this value - 1.
>
> spark.blacklist.application.maxFailedExecutorsPerNode(default=2):     (Experimental)
>   How many different executors must be blacklisted for the entire
>   application, before the node is blacklisted for the entire
>   application. Blacklisted nodes will be automatically added back to the
>   pool of available resources after the timeout specified by
>   spark.blacklist.timeout. Note that with dynamic allocation, though,
>   the executors on the node may get marked as idle and be reclaimed by
>   the cluster manager.
>
> spark.blacklist.task.maxTaskAttemptsPerExecutor(default=1):   (Experimental)
>   For a given task, how many times it can be retried on one executor
>   before the executor is blacklisted for that task.